# R: Foreach Parallelized

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I want to run a function 100 times. The function itself contains a for loop that requires running 4000 time. I placed my code online on EC2 to run it on multiple cores but am not sure if I am doing it correctly as it doesn't reveal if its actually utilizing all cores. Does the code below make sense?

```
#arbitrary function:
x = function() {
    y=c()
    for(i in 1:4000){
        y=c(y,i)
    }
    return(y)
}

#helper Function
loop.helper<-function(n.times){
    results = list()
    for(i in 1:n.times){
        results[[i]] = x()
    }
    return(results)
}

#Parallel
require(foreach)
require(parallel)
require(doParallel)

cores = detectCores() #32
cl<-makeCluster(cores) #register cores
registerDoParallel(cl, cores = cores)
```

This is my problem, I am not sure if its should be this:

```
out <- foreach(i=1:cores) %dopar% {
     helper(n.times = 100)
}
```

or should it be this:

```
out <- foreach(i=1:100) %dopar% {
     x()
}
```

Both of them work, but I am not sure if the first one will distribute the task to the 32 cores I have or does it automatically do it in the second `foreach` loop implementation.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
out <- foreach(i=1:100) %dopar% {
     x()
}
```

Is the correct way to do it. The `foreach` package will automatically distribute the 100 tasks among the registered cores (32 cores, in your case).

If you read the package documentation, you can read some of the examples and it should become extra clear to you.

EDIT:

To respond to @user1234440's comment:

Some considerations:

There is some time required to set up and manage the parallel tasks (e.g. setting up the multiple jobs to run concurrently, and then combining the results at the end). For some trivial tasks or small jobs, sometimes running a parallel process takes longer than the simple sequential loop simply because setting up the parallel processes takes up more time than it saves. However, for most tasks that require some non-trivial computations, you will likely experience speed improvements.

Also, from what I have read, you will see diminishing returns as you use more cores (e.g. using 8 cores may not necessarily be 2x faster than using 4 cores, but may only be 1.5x faster). In addition, from my personal experience, using ALL the available cores on my system resulted in some performance degradation. I think this was because I was dedicating all of my system resources to the parallel job and it was slowing down my other system processes.

That being said, I have almost always experienced speed improvements when using the parallel processing power offered by the `foreach` function. For your example of running 100 jobs with 32 cores, 4 cores will receive 4 jobs, and the other 28 cores will receive 3 jobs. Now it will be as if 32 computers are running mini `for` loops, iterating through the 4 or 3 jobs that were distributed to each of the cores. After each loop is completed, the results are combined and returned to you.

If running the 100 tasks is completed faster with a simple `for` loop than with a parallel `foreach` loop, then running these 100 tasks in a regular `for` loop 4000 times will be faster than running the 100 tasks in a parallelized `foreach` loop 4000 times.

Comment: if I have 32 cores but am running the simulations say 10 times, does that improve the performance over say just doing it without parallel?

Comment: @user1234440 I edited my answer to answer your question as best I could.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to execute the function "x" 100 times, you can do that with:

```
out <- foreach(i=1:100) %dopar% {
    x()
}
```

This correctly returns a list of 100 vectors. Your other solution is wrong because it will execute the function "x" `cores * 100` times, returning a list of `cores` lists of 100 vectors.

You may be confused because it is common to write parallel loops that use one iteration for each core. For instance, you could also execute "x" 100 times like this:

```
out <- foreach(i=1:cores, .combine='c') %dopar% {
  results <- vector('list', 25)
  for (j in 1:25) {
    results[[j]] <- x()
  }
  results
}
```

This also returns a list of 100 vectors, and it will be somewhat more efficient. This technique is called "task chunking", and it can give significantly better performance when the tasks are short. Your second solution is almost like this, except the helper function should execute fewer iterations, and the resulting lists should be combined, which I do by using `c` as the combine function.

It's important to realize that you can't control the number of cores that are used via the iteration variable in the foreach loop: that is controlled via the `registerDoParallel` function. But most parallel backends, including doParallel, will map `cores` tasks to `cores` workers. It's also important to realize that you don't truly control the number of cores that will be used by the `cores` worker processes. You control the number of processes that will be created to execute tasks when you call `makeCluster`, but ultimately it is up to the operating system to schedule those processes on the cores of the CPU, so the "cores" argument is something of a misnomer.

Also note that for your example, you should call `registerDoParallel` as:

```
registerDoParallel(cl)
```

Since you specified a value for the `cl` argument, the `cores` argument is ignored, however the documentation doesn't make that clear.

Comment: I am new to running tasks in parallel. In all honesty, I crashed the 32 core machine on ec2 when I employed my code which utilized cpu 100%. Would it be safer to actually specify a cores number that is 20% less than what you have on your machine?

Comment: @user1234440 There may not have been enough memory to handle 32 worker processes. You could try running 4 workers and then use a tool (such as "top") to monitor how much memory each worker process uses, then increase the number to fit the machine.

Comment: Thanks Steve, one last question: is true that each core will be running their own instances of a function? So for example, in the above function `x`, I assume if i employ 4 cores, when the overhead is full and running, each core will be doing each of their own runs of running `x`? Core 1 will be running first until it reaches a read/write whereby it will allow core 2 to run until it reaches a maximum allowed running time.

Comment: Im employing a smaller amount of cores but ran into: `Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection`

Comment: @user1234440 Your last question can't really be answered in a comment, but if you create 4 worker processes on a multicore CPU then the OS will most like schedule them to run in parallel on the cores of the CPU. I'm not sure what you mean by "running first" and "maximum allowed running time".

Comment: @user1234440 An error in unserialize could mean many things because that is how the master reads the task results from the worker processes.  It basically means that a worker failed somehow or other.